# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError - com/myApp/Client.cypherCBC(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

My code is giving an error below;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/myApp/Client.cypherCBC(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

But it's working fine in an another local environment. My code so far is below;

```
try {
    System.out.println("Encrypted CBC passwd : "
         + Client.cypherCBC("CypherThePassword"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like maybe the underlying dependencies have changed (read: the JARs are not the same in both places).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass an array of Strings

Comment: Add the code of `cypherCBC()` and the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 8):

This is due to a run-time JAR or class mismatch. the "Client" class which was there at the time you compile your application has a static method "cypherCBC" which gets String parameter, but at run-time class loader has loaded the "Client" class which doesn't have that kind of method (same name with same signature).

if you can debug the application at runtime, put a break-point at the line which exception was thrown, then try to evaluate following expression,

```
Client.class.getResource("Client.class")
```

, then you can find where the class has been leaded from, then you can decompile and try to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Due to working in projection (remote machine) am unable to debug and not even see build path. Jars are in src folder and build.xml have jars location as pathelement which is in src folder. But running Client.class.getResource("Client.class") gives me 

jar:file:/vobs/vob_central/gaia/lib/gas.jar!/com/aldata/gaia/server/impl/service/Client.class
Note here am having new gas.jar and location /vobs/vob_central/gaia/lib/gas.jar having older jar. But even though im having my new jar in src folder and it should take this path only.

Comment: then the class has been loaded from the jar /vobs/vob_central/gaia/lib/gas.jar .  i didnt get you about the "src" folder, is it a folder in the deployed env. i assume that you are suing java default class loader which is URLListClass loader, this loader has list of URLs for all jars which is mentioned in the -classpath. it goes through the urls based on the given order , so this /vobs/vob_central/gaia/lib/gas.jar is on the top op the list and the jar you wanted is in the bottom of the list

Comment: one more thing, even though your application runs in a remote machine, you can try remote debugging. if firewalls or access rights doesn't allow to do that, try to dump the complete application to your local machine

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while running a web application in Weblogic.
The reason for this error is there are two versions of classes are in the environment.To fix this you have to figure out which .class is using at the run time.
I used following to identify which class is loaded at run time.

> -verbose:class

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicate class on your classpath.
So, That is why JVM is getting confused that which one needs to pick because both classes have a same method with a different signature that you are trying to call.